# Can TPM-backed full-disk encryption feature on ubuntu 23.10 be used to encrypt secondary hard disk except for the OS one?

Tags: encryption

I have already used this TPM-backed full-disk encryption feature to encrypt the OS disk during new installation of Ubuntu 23.10 successfully. And test passed when I attached this disk to another Ubuntu system, it can not be mounted successfully.
Since TPM-backed full-disk encryption is a new feature on ubuntu 23.10, there is less document on Internet which describe how to use it to encrypt secondary disk except for the OS one.
Is it possible to do that with the same methodology of encrypt the OS disk? If it is possible, how to do it?

Comment: Alternatively you can put the keyfile on the OS disk

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have already think about your suggestion. This solution is a good idea, which use LUKS to encrypt secondary hard disk and store the its keyfile in the TPM encrypted OS disk, that protect keyfile from accessing by other ones. Is it possible to store the encryption keyfile or passphrases in TPM chipset like what did for OS disk?

Comment: IIRC the TPM is too small to store a keyfile or passphrase. The TPM just stores a fixed random state that is mixed with attestation about the boot environment to get a hash that is mixed with the rest of the key in the LUKS header. It should be possible to copy the same hash to use with the secondary disk, but then you need to audit the security of key reuse